# How to redirect to a specific page after pressing submit button (RAILS 7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After filling my sign up form and clicking submit, it redirects me to my root page, which I don't want to, I want it to redirect to a specific page I created.  I'm working on rails 7, I use de devise gem.

my registration_controller.rb

```
class  RegistrationController < ApplicationController 
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected
  
    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:prénom, :nom, :age, :gender, :tel_number])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:update, keys: [:prénom, :nom])
    end
    end
```

my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :information
  devise_for :accounts

  root "pages#home"



  devise_scope :account do
    get 'accounts/sign_out' => "devise/sessions#destroy"
end

  get 'accounts/verify_email', to: 'pages#VerifyEmail'
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end
```

i tried to do this in my registration_controller.rb without success.

```
 def new
      @account = Account.new
    end
  
    def create
      @account = Account.new(params[:accounts])
      if @account.save
        redirect_to accounts_verify_email
      else
        render :new
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, base your registration controller on `Devise::RegistrationsController`.

And then you have this method that you can override.

```rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/an/example/path' # Or :prefix_to_your_route
  end
end
```

You can use any path helper method as well. `resource` is available just in case if you have more authenticatable models. But I guess you won't need that.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it still don't work :/

Answer (score 0):

First you need tell the router to use custom Devise registrations controller

```rb
# config/routes.rb

devise_for :accounts, { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

And than create it and override `after_sign_up_path_for` Devise method

```rb
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  private

  def after_sign_up_path_for(_resource)
    some_specific_path
  end
end
```